# Why does the first navigation controller takes precedence?

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

This is the standard overall setup for Master Detail project.

[image]

When I change the background color of the first navigation bar, its also set like that when I go to the detail view. Even if I give the detail view's navigation bar a different color. Why is this? Also the color isn't even the color I set, which I suppose is a different question. ;) )

Comment: You don't change a navigation bar's background color. You change its tint color, or give it a background image. - Also, are you running this project on iPad or iPhone? It makes a big difference. In other words, are you seeing the split view, or are you pushing the detail view onto the master view?

Comment: iPhone. The tint color only effects the text though.

Comment: Setting the background color still has an effect .

Comment: Not the simple tint color. The _bar_ tint color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second navigation controller is only there for the iPad situation where the two navigation controllers are seen side by side (split view "expanded"). And if you were running this on iPad, you would indeed see two navigation controllers, each with its own navigation bar, and they could have different colors.

But that is not *your* situation. You're running this on iPhone. So the split view is "collapsed", which means that the detail view is pushed into the master view navigation controller.

This, in turn, has a very special result: the second navigation controller becomes sort of a red herring. You can't actually push a navigation controller onto a navigation controller. So the second navigation controller is effectively ripped out of the story, by a kind of sleight-of-hand private to Apple. Thus, its navigation bar is never seen, because it, itself, is never seen. Only the second detail view (the second table view) appears, pushed into the *first* navigation controller.